# Capture a Shift and Click event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't seem to be able to capture two events at the same time. I am trying to capture the Shift and Click (mouse click) event.

I have no problem capturing each action separately but not the two together.

Has anybody done some research on that particular problem?

Answer (score 104):

Yes:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        alert("shift+click")
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 24):

You can check the [event.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey) boolean property.

```
$(selector).click(function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        //....
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is the same answer as above.  They were answered at almost exactly the same time.

Comment: This is the same comment as above. It was stating the obvious.

Answer (score 9):

Worth note:

to detect Ctrl or "Meta" (Cmd key on OS X)

```
$(document).click(function(e)
    {
        if (e.ctrlKey)
        {
            alert("ctrl+click");
        }
    });

$(document).click(function(e)
    {
        if (e.metaKey)
        {
            alert("CMD+click");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `shiftKey` property of the `event` object that you receive in your `click` handler to check whether the shift key was down when the user clicked.

**EDIT**: `shiftKey`, not `shift`

Answer (score 3):

A nice library to handle key press events is shortcut.js, available [here](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/). It is very good.

You can even capture <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> at the same time which is something I was looking for.