# jquery keyup function check if number

Tags: jquery, function, character, keyup

i am trying to create an input field where the user can only type in numbers. this function is already working almost fine for me:

```
        $('#p_first').keyup(function(event){
        if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
            var value = $(this).val();

            $(this).val(value.substr(0,value.length-1));
        }
    });
```

but the problem is, whe the user holds the key with an character the function keyup is not triggering.... any ideas how i can forbid this?

Comment: holds which key?  Given a little bit more description of the cause of the issue?

Comment: any key... input type=text... and the user is holding for example "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" so the function keyup() is not triggering until he stops holding the key "a"

Comment: Thanks for providing more issue, I think my proposed solution should solve your issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try binding to the `keypress` event instead of `keyup`.  It gets fired repeatedly when a key is held down.  When the key pressed is not a number you can call `preventDefault()` which will keep the key from being placed in the input tag.

```
   $('#p_first').keypress(function(event){

       if(event.which != 8 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
           event.preventDefault(); //stop character from entering input
       }

   });
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rTWrb/2/

Comment: i have tried, but the new charakter is while the function keypress is running not in the textfield yet, so i cannot delet it with substr()

Comment: one thing... a cannot delete numbers now :D

Comment: @AdamSam You should also ignore: arrows, delete key, when text selected with mouse and block space button

Comment: @KevinBowersox I've a similar requirement..but in my case the user can enter a negative number also..so how to allow the user to enter "-" sign only in the first position of the number

Comment: @KevinBowersox Hi, it is working superbly on web but when I tried to do the same from mobile, its not working, any idea on how to make it work on mobile devices

Comment: to allow for decimal point ...  var enteredChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
if(event.which != 8 && (isNaN(enteredChar) && enteredChar!='.') ) ....

Comment: @DAB I think the decimal point check needs to be something like: `event.which != 190`. For me, `enteredChar!='.'` didn't work

Comment: What does 'event.which = 8' mean?

Answer (score 6):

I decided to use the answer provided by @Rahul Yadav, but it is erroneous since it doesn't consider num pad keys, which have different codes.

Here, you can see a [excerpt of the code table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781360/1073950):

Here the function I implemented:

```
function isNumberKey(e) {
    var result = false; 
    try {
        var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        //console.log(err);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution:

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DbRTj/

Same questions:

- [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)
- [jQuery: what is the best way to restrict “number”-only input for
  textboxes? (allow decimal points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all)

Comment: @IagoMelanias What do you mean? You are talking about second input OR about topic starter code?

Comment: I'm talking about your code. If i use the keys at the right side of my keyboard, it doesn't work.

Comment: @IagoMelanias Press `NumLock` this should fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to check value of input, instead of pressed key. Because there are tabs, arrows, backspace and other characters that need to be checked when You use character code.

That code check input value after user pressed a key:

```
$('#p_first').keyup(function(){
    while(! /^(([0-9]+)((\.|,)([0-9]{0,2}))?)?$/.test($('#p_first').val())){
        $('#p_first').val($('#p_first').val().slice(0, -1));
    }
});
```

While loop remove last character until input value is valid. Regex `/^(([0-9]+)((\.|,)([0-9]{0,2}))?)?$/` validate integer and float number eg. "12,12", "12.1", "12.". **It is important that number "12." (dot at the end) also be valid!** Otherwise user can't enter any period.

And then on submit regex check for valid float number `([0-9]{1,2})` instead of `([0-9]{0,2})`:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if(! /^([0-9]+)((\.|,)([0-9]{1,2}))?$/.test($('#p_first').val())){
        $('#p_first').addClass('error');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**Notice:** It is better to assign `$('#p_first')` into variable. `var input = $('#p_first');`

Answer (score 0):

Try This..it may usefull.

```
<HTML>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="price" value="" style="width:100px;" field="Quantity" class="required">
</HTML>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#price').live('keyup',function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following function to check if a given string is number or not. This implementation works on keyup and keydown and also takes care of numpad keys

```
// Validate Numeric inputs
function isNumber(o) {
    return o == '' || !isNaN(o - 0);
}
```

Assuming that your key code on the keyup or keydown event is in keyCode variable:

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) {
        // Numpad keys
        keyCode -= 48;
}
console.log(isNumber(String.fromCharCode(keyCode)));
console.log(isNumber($(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(keyCode)));
```

Return false if the return value from isNumber is false:

```
    var txtVal = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    if (!isNumber(txtVal)) {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a key event, use `event.key` to get the actual value. To check if integer:

```
isFinite(event.key);
```

An easier HTML solution would be to use the `number` type input. It restricts to only numbers (kind of).

```
<input type="number">
```

Either way, you should clean all user input with:

```
string.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JavaScript:

  function isNumberKey(a){
  var x=a.val();
  a.val(x.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));

}

HTML:

     <td><input type="text" name="qty" onkeypress="onkeyup="return isNumberKey($(this));"" value="" style="width:100px;" field="Quantity" class="required"></td>
```

Comment: this returns true for escape?

Comment: That's function is wrong since it doesn't consider num pad keys, which have a different code. Please, see the alternative answer.

Comment: This function return true  if input is only  number .

Comment: Does not handle numpad keys