# how to give validation for " _ " or " . "(either any one) in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to validate the username with below condition

1. Accept only Characters and NUmbers
2. Accept " _ " or " . "(either any one)

Here is my code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [maxlength]="50" name="userName" placeholder="User Name"
#userName="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="UserName" (keypress)="userNameValidation($event)">



userNameValidation(event: any) {
  const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+$/
  const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
  if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me to write the either or  condition???

Comment: What is wrong with your current regex pattern?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891652/1736186

Comment: dont want to accept both.. either one

Comment: Can you try this const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+[\_\.]{1}$/

Answer (score 0):

How about using the JS string function `string.includes`? See the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
userNameValidation(event: any) {
  const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+$/
  const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
  
  let includesBothDotAndUScore = inputChar.includes("_") && inputChar.includes(".");

  if (!pattern.test(inputChar) || includesBothDotAndUScore) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Also, I believe you can use `UserName` in the place of `inputChar`.