# Detect CMD/CTRL click on select2-selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) on my website for handling search results. When the user clicks on an item in the result list the select2-selecting event is fired as it should and I've made it send the user to the selected result.

```
$('.select2').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
    window.location.href = 'item/' + e.object.id;
});
```

Can I somehow detect if the user holds down the <kbd>cmd</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> on Windows) key and open the page in a new tab?

Comment: What is the output of `window.console.log(e);`? It could be `if(e.ctrlKey)` like in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using duke's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript/11384018#11384018) and hluk's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781282/1523238). I came up with this solution:

```
$(document).bind('keyup keydown', function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){
        keyIsDown = true;
    }else{
        keyIsDown = false;
    }
});

$('.select2').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
    url = 'item/' + e.object.id;
    if(keyIsDown){
        var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    }else{
        window.location.href = scriptPath + 'item/' + e.object.id;
    }
});
```