# AJAX code sending GET request twice

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My TA says that GET request by following AJAX code is being sent twice. But I don't see how nor I am able to fix it. What is general approach how to deal with that?

It is simple page with search box giving advices as you type. Problem has to be somewhere in getByPrefix function.

JS code:

```
function set(arg)
{
    var searchtext = document.getElementById("searchtext");
    searchtext.value = arg.innerHTML;
    showMatches(searchtext);
}

function getByPrefix(prefix, callback)
{
    var prefixes = [];

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) // prepsani do jednoducheho indexovaneho pole
            {
                prefixes.push(response[i].drug);
            }

            callback(prefixes);         
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","prefixes.php?q="+prefix,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function action2(text)
{
    getByPrefix(text.value, showMatches);
}

function showMatches(text)
{
    var matches = text;

    var form = document.getElementById("search");
    var results = document.getElementById("results");

    if (results != null)
        form.removeChild(results);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "results";

    for (var i =0; i < matches.length; i++)
    {
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.className = "hidden";
        p.onclick =  (function(a) { return function(){ set(a); }})(p);
        p.innerHTML = matches[i];

        div.appendChild(p);
    }

    if (matches.length>1 && text.value != "")
        form.appendChild(div);

    if (matches.length==1 && text.value != matches[0])
        form.appendChild(div);
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
function head()
{
    global $db;
?>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <?php head_common(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
}

function body()
{
?>
<body>
    <?php heading(); ?>
   <div>
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" height="200" width="400"> 
    <form id="search" method="get" action="index.php">
        <p>
            <input name="page" value="results" type="hidden">
            <input name="part" value="1" type="hidden">
            <input name="hledej" id="searchtext" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="action2(this)" type="text">
            <button>Hledej</button>
        </p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php footer(); ?>
</body>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: For checking, use Js Console of Firebug or Chrome, set a rupture point in the definition of the function, and you'll see when is sending it

Comment: _"Problem has to be somewhere in getByPrefix function."_ - No it doesn't. It looks to me like `getByPrefix()` will make one ajax call. But you are calling it in response to every keyup event, so as the user types `getByPrefix()` will be called repeatedly. (As an aside, what's the point of testing `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` if there's no else case for if that object doesn't exist?)

Comment: Yeah, you can type one letter, but if it's capital, you need to hold shift, and after you release it `keyup` is triggered twice.

Comment: Yes! That is the problem @Carlos Write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably typing the capital letter, with `SHIFT` key, so once you release the keys the `keyup` event is triggered twice and you have 2 `AJAX` requests.

You can filter pressed keys using `eventData` param. For `SHIFT` key look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781142/jquery-or-javascript-how-determine-if-shift-key-being-pressed-while-clicking-an).

Comment: Well, but how to filter if keyup is char only?

Comment: @jb91 look at edits, and suggested follow up question.