# Make a date read ahead

Tags: javascript, date

I want to know if it is possible to modify the date below to read 2 weeks ahead, instead of reading the actual date?

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
  var now = new Date();
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  var monNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
  document.write(" " + dayNames[now.getDay()] + " " + monNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getDate() + ", " + now.getFullYear());
</script>
    
<!--End Date Script-->
```

Comment: Yes.  Search for *javascript add days to date* and add 14 to `now`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you google for it?

Comment: @Deleteman, i have tried so many and it didn't work.

Comment: @bobos as a recommendation for future questions, try to also add what you tried to do, that way it doesn't look like you suddenly had the need for this and the first thing you did was ask here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var daysToAdd = 14; 
var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(daysToAdd * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000));

var output = [
  dayNames[myDate.getDay()],
  monNames[myDate.getMonth()],
  myDate.getDate(),
].join(' ') + ', ' + myDate.getFullYear(); // "Thursday April 23, 2015"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sxmt22se/2/)

Comment: If the demo works, it's most likely a problem in your own code @bobos

Comment: @Andy, please could you demonstrate how it should be on the HTML file. Please!

Comment: @bobos, what HTML file? What are you asking?

Comment: @Andy I am a newbie and would like you to demonstrate in full how it should appear on the HTML file where the code is intended to be used. Thank

Comment: @Andy, For reference, you can see the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543303/allow-certain-characters-in-textbox   at the point where the teacher wrote "So your whole page should look like:"

Comment: It goes within `<script>...code...`</script>` tags. What you do with it after that is entirely up to you. I can't, and don't have the time, to give you a tutorial on HTML/JavaScript, I'm sorry.