# How do I trigger a shift click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently using element.trigger('click') to simulate a regular click, but how could I, using angular simulate a SHIFT-click?

Comment: Trigger a key down event for the shift, the click event, a key up event for the shift

Comment: element.trigger('click') doesn't actually "click" anything... It executes the click handler Javascript function for the element.

Comment: @PaulS: Note that a real shift-click doesn't require that the element already have the focus.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165222

Answer (score 2):

To anyone looking for the answer:

```
var clickEvent = $.Event('click');
clickEvent.shiftKey = event.shiftKey;
element.trigger(clickEvent);
```

Thanks to all that responded.

Comment: Just for reference, this uses JQuery so it's not something you can do with just Angular (or vanilla JS).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if anybody is looking for an updated Angular solution:

```
const trs: NodeListOf<HTMLTableRowElement> nativeElement.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");

const ev = new MouseEvent("click", { shiftKey: true });
trs[3].dispatchEvent(ev)
```

This will shift-click on the third table body row...